# Kotlin extension function for creating intent

Tags: android, kotlin

If I create a companion object function like this:

```
class MyActivity: Activity
{
   // ...

   companion object
   {
      fun createIntent(context: Context): Intent
      {
         return Intent(context, this::class.java.declaringClass)
      }
   }
}
```

then I have a handy way to create an intent:

```
val intent = MyActivity.createIntent(context)
```

Is there a way I could define something like this as an extension, so I wouldn't have to define that function for every Activity class?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way I could define something like this as an extension, so I wouldn't have to define that function for every Activity class?

```
inline fun <reified T> Context.createIntent() = Intent(this, T::class.java)
```

Usage:

```
context.createIntent<MyActivity>()
createIntent<MyActivity>() // If already in a context
```

Or if you prefer the style you showed in your question:

```
inline fun <reified T> T.createIntent(context : Context) =
    Intent(context, T::class.java)
```

Usage:

```
MyActivity.createIntent(this /* context */)
```

Comment: I had just come up with something similar.  (One correction, it needs to be T::class.java.declaringClass, since T is the companion class.)

2 questions though: why "inline"? and why "reified"?

Comment: You would not put this in a companion. Per your question, you wanted this "for every Activity class", so putting it in any one Activity's companion class would not make sense. This would be a free-standing function. `inline` is required for `reified`, and `reified` is required to know what type `T` actually is at compile time. See [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters).